# Unicorn Items prevent Sync to web DB

Tags: unicorn

I am not sure on which databases the Sitecore Items are synced to when I deploy my Sitecore solution to the CM system with the `Sync.ps1 script` and the `Unicorn.psm1`. I think the items are also synced to my Web Database, what I want to prevent. So that items are only created in Master and Core Database when I am Syncing items.

I've seen this in the `Unicorn.AutoPublish.config`

```
<unicornSyncEnd>
    <processor type="Unicorn.Pipelines.UnicornSyncEnd.TriggerAutoPublishSyncedItems, Unicorn">
        <PublishTriggerItemId>/sitecore/templates/Common/Folder</PublishTriggerItemId> 
        <TargetDatabases hint="list:AddTargetDatabase">
            <web>web</web>
        </TargetDatabases>
    </processor>
</unicornSyncEnd>
```

Can I remove the web here? Or has this nothing to do where the Items are Synced to?

I only want new items and templates get to the web Database when I publish my content.

Comment: It would be highly irregular to configure Unicorn to sync directly to "web" - even if it is possible in theory. You need to disable your AutoPublish.config to disable the publish that happens at the end - as you point out. You should not edit the file however.

Comment: @MarkCassidy so it would be enough to just set the required role to Standalone for the file content right?

Comment: Normally, yes. Your upstream CM server would traditionally be in the "ContentManagement" role. But locally I don't see why you would need publishing either - local environments are usually configured in live-mode.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommened for higher environments to disable the unicorn autopublish, however you shouldn't edit the file directly as in future upgrades it might be required to update/overwrite it. One option would be to handle it in the deploy pipeline using a config transform for example `Unicorn.AutoPublish.transform.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement">
    <pipelines>
      <unicornSyncEnd>
        <processor>
          <TargetDatabases hint="list:AddTargetDatabase" xdt:Transform="Replace" />
        </processor>
      </unicornSyncEnd>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This will just remove the web database which is the first check in the `TriggerAutoPublishSyncedItems` processor: https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn/blob/master/src/Unicorn/Pipelines/UnicornSyncEnd/TriggerAutoPublishSyncedItems.cs